# how to Print a function without printing the Return type in Python?

Tags: python

I want to print something like this:

```
Current Hand: a e i i n r t
```

`a e i i n r t`, however is the output of the following function with no return type:

```
def abcd(hand):
  for letter in hand:
     print letter
  print
```

I use `print "Current Hand:",abcd(hand)` to do so but I get the following op:

```
Current Hand: a e i i n r t None
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: That function *doesn't return anything*. Printing is **not** the same as returning. `None` is what functions return by default if you don't return anything explicit. Why not move `'Current Hand:'` *inside* the function?

Comment: Not in a position to edit that function. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Why not? And if you don't want to print what the function returns, *don't do that* - just call it and ignore what it returns.

Comment: The function isn't written by me and cannot be modified unfortunately.Also if i were to simple call the function wouldn't it place the a e i i n r t in the next line and not the same line as Current Hand?

Comment: Not if you suppress the new line on the first `print`. Do some research!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) the function doesn't return anything.

Try something like this:

```
def abcd(hand):
    return ' '.join(hand)
```

Then you can call `print "Current Hand:", abcd(hand)` and you'll get a space-separated string (assuming `hand` is some kind of iterable, [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) builds a string out of it).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to output the letters you should return them as a string.

```
def abcd(hand):
  return ' '.join(hand)

>>> print("Current Hand:",abcd('aeiinrt'))
Current Hand: a e i i n r t
>>> abcd('aeiinrt')
'a e i i n r t'
```

Read about [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) here in the docs and a quick tutorial on how to use it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Don't print the result of the function, just call the function. The following should do it. Notice that the function call is in its own line. The comma in your original code is causing the return value of `abcd` to be passed to `print`.

```
print "Current Hand:"
abcd(hand)
```